# How to copy array of char using strncpy_s

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to copy an array of char to a buffer (also an array of `char` but larger size). I'm using `strncpy_s` to do this which is quite straightforward. However, the result is not what I expected. Here is the code

```
int r = strncpy_s(lOutMessage.messageBuffer+1, 4, lIndexChar, 4);
// lIndexChar is an array of char with size 4, 1, 0, 0, 0 (char converted to int) -> char lIndexChar[4];
// lOutMessage.messageBuffer is also an array of char -> char messageBuffer[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
```

I expect the `1, 0, 0, 0` values to be copied to the buffer. However, only the first two copied properly. The result after copying the values are `1, 0, -2, -2`. I'm not sure how it goes to -2. Any idea why this is happening? Any solution?

Comment: You should create a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].  We don't have enough to go on here.

Comment: I can't help without a [mre], but do consider using `std::string` if at all possible

Comment: Both the question and the cause are perfectly clear, guys.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. Still not used to the rules. Problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating your "array of `char`" as a C-string. That is, a buffer that logically ends with a null terminator (even when it physically may contain further, trailing, bytes).

But *it isn't one*. It is a buffer of arbitrary values, including zeroes.

`strncpy` and friends work on C-strings, and typically stop at a zero value (i.e. a null terminator). Indeed, [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) says that `strncpy`:

> Copies at most `count` characters of the character array pointed to by `src` (including the terminating null character, **but not any of the characters that follow the null character**) to character array pointed to by `dest`.

As a result, the remaining bytes of the destination array remain unchanged, so you're probably seeing the result of reading uninitialised (and therefore unspecified) values. At the very least, they're values you left in there before.

You probably wanted [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::copy(lIndexChar, lIndexChar+4, lOutMessage.messageBuffer+1);
```

…or its C friend, [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), if you're feeling old and unsafe. (That would be the direct non-string analogue of your current approach.)

---

> I'm using strncpy_s to do this which is quite straightforward.

In general, if a function you're using is not doing what you wanted it to do, look it up in the documentation to make sure that it does what you think it does. Maybe it's not as straightforward as you'd assumed.

Comment: this solves my problem. Thank you.Not really sure why they have to put strncpy if there is std::copy to do the same thing (?)

Comment: @JosTimantaTarigan Who is "they"? Do you mean the language designers? It's because they are different functions that do different things and they both have uses depending on what you're trying to do. It's just that, today, `strncpy` is not the right tool for your job.

Comment: Since when does `strncpy()` handle null terminated strings, instead of fixed-length buffers containing a zero-padded string?

Comment: @Deduplicator What is the difference between the two? At least in this context.

Comment: `strncpy` neither assumes the source to be null terminated, nor guarantees the destination to be so. Instead, it guarantees to null pad it, whether that means n or 0 null characters, which often looks like supremely inefficient null termination, but sometimes doesn't. Thus `strncpy` is not a null terminated string function, and it and `strncpy_s` are at best false friends.

Comment: @Deduplicator I see it the other way around: `strncpy` does assume the source to be null terminated, but is aware that the requested range of the view into that source may end before the null termination. See, it's just down to interpretation. Either way it doesn't really matter because the semantics are bolded in the quote above and that's all the OP needs to know.

Comment: Well, your quote is too short. But yes, that part can be looked at sideways.